# Camera and mirror equivalent to two cameras looking at same object

Tags: matrix, camera, mirror

Given i) a camera which looks at a point X in space and ii) a mirror that is in the field of view of the camera so that the camera also sees the mirrored point X' of X. X will be projected to the image point x in the camera image plane and X' will be projected to x' in the image plane. How can it be shown that this situation is equivalent to the situation with two cameras each looking at the point X in space? All tips are appreciate.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see a programming question here

Comment: That is true. But must it be a programming question? It is about mathematics and computer science. So i thought it would be better to post it here than in the Mathematics or Programmers community. If this is the wrong place i will move it to Mathematics of course.